# Set custom locales in Gnome3 (on Fedora 20)

Tags: fedora, gnome3, locale

I've created my own custom `locale`s and placed them in `/etc/locale.conf` which successfully takes effect if I log in on a virtual console (Ctrl+Alt+F2). In my Gnome3 session those variables are not set, though. For terminal applications I could just place them in the `.bashrc` but that won't help me with graphical applications like Thunderbird and Pidgin.

I have tried to follow these hints: [Locale settings in shell initialization not used by GNOME session](https://answers.launchpad.net/gnome-common/+question/60699#comment-2) and even emulated the bug in [Locale - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale#Changed_everything_and_my_GNOME_is_still_using_wrong_language.3F) by creating a `.pam_environment` file, but the `locale`s are still those set by Gnome3. There is a configuration dialogue in the Gnome settings but it only allows to set a very limited set of predefined `locale` combinations and no way to customize them.

The relevant files in my home directory:

```
user@localhost:~$ ls -lah .dmrc .pam_environment .session .xsession .xsessionrc
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 16 12. Jun 08:57 .dmrc -> /etc/locale.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 16 11. Jun 20:23 .pam_environment -> /etc/locale.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 16 12. Jun 09:09 .session -> /etc/locale.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 16 12. Jun 09:07 .xsession -> /etc/locale.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user  9 13. Jun 11:22 .xsessionrc -> .xsession
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 66 13. Jun 11:13 .profile

user@localhost:~$ cat .profile 
source /etc/locale.conf
```

The contents of `/etc/locale.conf`:

```
LANG="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="de_MY.utf8" # NB: de_MY
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.utf8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.utf8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.utf8"
```

Does anyone know how to set custom `locale`s in Gnome3 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Background Information

I tested the solution on Fedora 21 with GNOME Shell 3.14.4, but I believe it can be applied to other versions as well.

First thing to understand is that GNOME desktop environment overrides the system-wide locale definitions and thus is not affected by `/etc/locale.conf`. In addition, there are might be applications that have their own locale configuration and don't use the system or GNOME settings at all. In this guide I will describe a way to customize the locale settings to your needs and GNOME and the system will be consistent from the locale perspective.

---

## Checking Current Locale Status

### System-wide Settings

From [Fedora 21 System Administrator's Guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-System_Locale_and_Keyboard_Configuration.html):

> System-wide locale settings are stored in the `/etc/locale.conf` file, which is read at early boot by the **systemd** daemon. The locale settings configured in `/etc/locale.conf` are inherited by every service or user, unless individual programs or individual users override them.

To see the current locale status we can run:

```
$ localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
                  LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
                  LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
                  LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
                  LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
                  LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
```

### GNOME Settings

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.system.locale region
'en_US.UTF-8'
```

GNOME has only one setting. By giving a quick look at the [source code of gnome-control-center](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-control-center/plain/panels/region/cc-region-panel.c?id=GNOME_CONTROL_CENTER_3_14_4) it seems that when the `set_localed_locale()` function is called, it sets all the following categories (LC_TIME, LC_NUMERIC, LC_MONETARY, LC_MEASUREMENT, LC_PAPER) to the same one locale defined in `org.gnome.system.locale region`.

Mixing different locale settings seems impossible without creating a custom locale, but fortunately it's not a very complex task.

---

## Creating Custom Locale

I think the easiest way to explain is by example. In my specific case I wanted to have a custom locale, primarily based on Hebrew (**he_IL**) but with LC_NAME, LC_MESSAGES from **en_US** and LC_TIME (with modified `first_weekday` and `first_workday`) from **en_GB**.

### Grabbing Locale Definition Files

You should have an idea which locales you want to mix. First we need to locate the related  definition files, which can be found in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/`.
Back to my example, I needed the following: **he_IL**, **en_US** and **en_GB**. I set up a working folder in my home and copied the required files into it:

```
$ cd /usr/share/i18n/locales
$ mkdir -v ~/custom-locale ; cp -v he_IL en_US en_GB ~/custom-locale/
```

### Creating a New Definition File

I decided to call my locale **hc_IL** and took **he_IL** as a basis. The following lines create a new file `hc_IL` with the contents from `he_IL` and on the way replace all the occurrences of a string **he_IL** inside the file with **hc_IL**.

```
$ cd ~/custom-locale/
$ sed 's/he_IL/hc_IL/g' he_IL > hc_IL
```

### Modifying the New Definition File

Now we can customize the new locale to our needs. Open the newly created file `~/custom-locale/hc_IL` with your favorite text editor. I use **vim** (it has proper syntax highlighting for locale definition files):

```
$ vim ~/custom-locale/hc_IL
```

For those who haven't chosen their favorite editor yet and **vim** is not their cup of tea, can use **gedit** :)

```
$ gedit ~/custom-locale/hc_IL
```

The file structure is not very complicated. Essentially, it is constructed from sections. From **locale(5)** man pages:

> The locale definition has one part for each locale category.  Each part
>   can  be  copied  from  another  existing  locale or can be defined from
>   scratch.  If the category should be copied, the only valid  keyword  in
>   the  definition is **copy** followed by the name of the locale which should be copied.

The notion of **copy** is very useful. It saves time and the resulting file is clear and concise. For example, instead of copying entire sections around, you can have:

```
LC_MESSAGES
copy "en_US"
END LC_MESSAGES
```

The complete documentation on a locale definition file can be accessed via:

```
$ man 5 locale
```

Although, if you just want to create a custom locale, which is a mix of existing ones there's no need to understand every detail.

In my case I modified the following categories and keywords:

- **LC_IDENTIFICATION**

  ```
  title      "Custom Hebrew locale"
  source     "mydomain.ws"
  address    "http:////www.mydomain.ws"
  contact    ""
  email      "admin@mydomain.ws"
  tel        ""
  fax        ""
  language   "Hebrew"
  territory  "Israel"
  revision   "1.0"
  date       "2015-04-21"
  ```

  **Note:** All the "*category..*" lines in the **LC_IDENTIFICATION** section have been modified during the file creation using `sed`. So we don't need to touch them anymore.
- **LC_TIME**

  I copied the complete section from **en_GB** and modified only the lines that indicate the first day of week and the first work day:

  ```
  first_weekday 1
  first_workday 1
  ```
- The rest of the categories I left as they are or replaced their content with the **copy** directive as in:

  ```
  LC_NAME
  copy "en_US"
  END LC_NAME
  ```

That's it, the definition file is ready. Don't forget to save the file :)

### Compile and Copy the New Locale

Compilation of the new locale is done using the following command as **root** or using **sudo**. Replace `hc_IL` with your locale:

```
$ sudo localedef  -c -v -i hc_IL -f UTF-8 hc_IL.UTF-8
```

If the compilation is successful the compiled locale data is added to the  archive file `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`.

Copy the new locale definition file to the locale definitions directory. Replace `hc_IL` with your locale:

```
$ sudo cp -v hc_IL /usr/share/i18n/locales/
```

---

## Activating the New Locale

In this step we want to configure the system and GNOME to use the new locale.

### System-wide Settings

Edit the `/etc/locale.conf` file as **root** and set every line that starts with `LC_` to your new locale. For example:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=hc_IL.utf8
LC_TIME=hc_IL.utf8
LC_MONETARY=hc_IL.utf8
LC_PAPER=hc_IL.utf8
LC_MEASUREMENT=hc_IL.utf8
```

### GNOME Settings

To activate the new locale in GNOME run the following command. Replace `hc_IL` with your locale:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.system.locale region "hc_IL.utf8"
```

---

## Validating the New Settings

The last step is to validate that everything works as expected. To reload all the settings the easiest for me was to reboot.

- Refer to the section "Checking Current Locale Status" to check that the system configuration is correct.
- Use GNOME Shell and locale dependent applications (graphical and console) and check that they behave as expected with the new locale. E.g. if you customized LC_TIME you can run the `date` command to validate the date format:

  ```
  $ date +%x
  21/04/15
  ```

**Note:** Everything was tested on Fedora 21 with GNOME 3.14. Other Linux distributions may require additional or different steps.

Please comment if you find any issues with the instructions.

Comment: I can confirm this works on Fedora 22 with Cinnamon. It will most likely work with GNOME as well.

Comment: I'm sure if they try really hard, they could make setting up custom locales just a little bit harder still.

Comment: I love GNOME but this is ridiculous. At least leave a way for power users to set their locale settings the way they want. I want a US locale for most things, but my printer uses A4 paper...

Comment: This was 4 years ago. Is this still the case? I can't believe I cant set regional settings individually, we have these since the dark ages elsewhere.

Comment: Note that en_IL was merged in 2016 to gnome, so no need for a custom locale in this case.
https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2016/04/16/en_il-english-locale-for-israel/

Comment: in Ubuntu 20.04 the `/etc/locale.conf` file does not exist. Any idea which is the corresponding new file, and if the procedure above still applies otherwise?

Comment: @pglpm try running  `man locale.conf`. You may just need to create a new file if it doesn't exist.