# Best practice to customize date/time format system-wide?

Tags: linux, date, locale

#### TL;DR

What is the best practice for customizing my date and time format settings, while sticking to the DRY-principle, i.e. without repeating stuff unnecessarily?

---

I'd like to customize **exclusively the date and time format** for my system, while sticking to the rest of the locale as is. I know that environment variable `LC_TIME` will make it possible to customize that aspect only by pointing to an alternate locale. Since I am using Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 to be precise), I want to use the format understood by `localedef` as input.

I have read the following three pieces of documentation:

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/localedef.1posix.html
- https://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/

The last one was particularly helpful.

Now, I **only** want to customize the section for **`LC_TIME`** and would like to inherit verything else.

So I copied `en_US` to a file named `isodate` in `/usr/share/i18n/locales` and adjusted the values I care about. After sifting through the documentation I decided also to replace all other section contents with a `copy`-keyword.

**Question:** It's not clear to me what method is supposed to be best practice. Does anyone know that (or even another alternative than those given by me)?

For example, since I care only about a few values (`d_t_fmt`, `d_fmt`, `t_fmt`, `t_fmt_ampm`, `am_pm`, `date_fmt`) it would be sweet to **inherit** all of `en_US` for `LC_TIME` and then merely overwrite those values with my ISO-like format (ISO 8601). However, the documentation about `copy` states (emphasis mine):

> **copy**
>
> Specify the name of an existing locale which shall be used as the definition of this category. If this keyword is specified, *no other keyword shall be specified.*

This means I cannot simply throw in a `copy` and then add more keywords.

Also, might it be legit to only define the `LC_TIME` section or will `localedef` outright refuse to compile that?

---

What I came up with so far:

```
escape_char /
comment_char %

LC_IDENTIFICATION
copy "en_US"
END LC_IDENTIFICATION

LC_CTYPE
copy "en_US"
END LC_CTYPE

LC_COLLATE
copy "en_US"
END LC_COLLATE

LC_MONETARY
copy "en_US"
END LC_MONETARY

LC_NUMERIC
copy "en_US"
END LC_NUMERIC

LC_TIME
abday   "<U0053><U0075><U006E>";"<U004D><U006F><U006E>";/
    "<U0054><U0075><U0065>";"<U0057><U0065><U0064>";/
    "<U0054><U0068><U0075>";"<U0046><U0072><U0069>";/
    "<U0053><U0061><U0074>"
day "<U0053><U0075><U006E><U0064><U0061><U0079>";/
    "<U004D><U006F><U006E><U0064><U0061><U0079>";/
    "<U0054><U0075><U0065><U0073><U0064><U0061><U0079>";/
    "<U0057><U0065><U0064><U006E><U0065><U0073><U0064><U0061><U0079>";/
    "<U0054><U0068><U0075><U0072><U0073><U0064><U0061><U0079>";/
    "<U0046><U0072><U0069><U0064><U0061><U0079>";/
    "<U0053><U0061><U0074><U0075><U0072><U0064><U0061><U0079>"

week    7;19971130;7
first_weekday   1
first_workday   2
abmon   "<U004A><U0061><U006E>";"<U0046><U0065><U0062>";/
    "<U004D><U0061><U0072>";"<U0041><U0070><U0072>";/
    "<U004D><U0061><U0079>";"<U004A><U0075><U006E>";/
    "<U004A><U0075><U006C>";"<U0041><U0075><U0067>";/
    "<U0053><U0065><U0070>";"<U004F><U0063><U0074>";/
    "<U004E><U006F><U0076>";"<U0044><U0065><U0063>"
mon "<U004A><U0061><U006E><U0075><U0061><U0072><U0079>";/
    "<U0046><U0065><U0062><U0072><U0075><U0061><U0072><U0079>";/
    "<U004D><U0061><U0072><U0063><U0068>";/
    "<U0041><U0070><U0072><U0069><U006C>";/
    "<U004D><U0061><U0079>";/
    "<U004A><U0075><U006E><U0065>";/
    "<U004A><U0075><U006C><U0079>";/
    "<U0041><U0075><U0067><U0075><U0073><U0074>";/
    "<U0053><U0065><U0070><U0074><U0065><U006D><U0062><U0065><U0072>";/
    "<U004F><U0063><U0074><U006F><U0062><U0065><U0072>";/
    "<U004E><U006F><U0076><U0065><U006D><U0062><U0065><U0072>";/
    "<U0044><U0065><U0063><U0065><U006D><U0062><U0065><U0072>"
% Appropriate date and time representation (%c)
%   "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
d_t_fmt "<U0025><U0059><U002D><U0025><U006D><U002D><U0025><U0064><U0020><U0025><U0048><U003A><U0025><U004D><U003A><U0025><U0053>"
%
% Appropriate date representation (%x)
%   "%Y-%m-%d"
d_fmt   "<U0025><U0059><U002D><U0025><U006D><U002D><U0025><U0064>"
%
% Appropriate time representation (%X)
%   "%H:%M:%S"
t_fmt   "<U0025><U0048><U003A><U0025><U004D><U003A><U0025><U0053>"
%
t_fmt_ampm ""
%
am_pm   "";""
%
% Appropriate date representation (date(1))   "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
date_fmt    "<U0025><U0059><U002D><U0025><U006D><U002D><U0025><U0064><U0020><U0025><U0048><U003A><U0025><U004D><U003A><U0025><U0053>"
END LC_TIME

LC_MESSAGES
copy "en_US"
END LC_MESSAGES

LC_PAPER
copy "en_US"
END LC_PAPER

LC_NAME
copy "en_US"
END LC_NAME


LC_ADDRESS
copy "en_US"
END LC_ADDRESS

LC_TELEPHONE
copy "en_US"
END LC_TELEPHONE

LC_MEASUREMENT
copy "en_US"
END LC_MEASUREMENT
```

Comment: It's ok to only define one section and _copy_ the [other ones](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197693)...

Comment: You might want to take a look at en_DK.UTF-8 :) I guess it's what you want.

Comment: I created a very similar locale recently and as Pierre-Alain suggested I used en_DK.UTF-8 as my template. I don't think that there are any strict best practices as can be seen by looking at the differences between the standard locales that are shipped with most Linux distributions. You can read about how I solved my problem on my [web site](https://www.gam3.net/2018/08/25/creating-a-new-locale-and-using-it-on-debian/) and look at the final result on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gam3/en_NL).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in some of the comments, you can either copy the rest of the sections and customize `LC_TIME` in your custom locales file, or configure `LC_TIME` in `/etc/locale.conf`.  As the `locale.conf(5)` man-page suggests, you could also use the kernel commandline option `locale.LC_TIME=` to override the setting at boot time.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I didn't quite get your edit on the question, but whatever. My main issue is not so much to get a particular effect (I think my question demonstrates I have found it). The core of my question is whether there is a canonical way of doing this and what it is. The reason I asked it because without a canonical way I run the risk of changing stuff that I shouldn't change and run into all kinds of conflicts (such as with package management). You probably don't see them, but there were three (now deleted) answers like yours before. Still +1.