# Change a locale definition (as opposed to a locale setting)

Tags: date, locale

**Preliminary remark**: This question is **not** about *setting* a locale by changing `LC_ALL`, `LC_TIME`, `LANG`, etc., it's rather about changing a locale *definition*, e.g. in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/de_DE`, or respectively, to get suggestions about more appropriate options than changing those system settings.

The **intent** is to obtain *ISO time representations* `%Y-%m-%d` and `%H:%M:%S` without undesired side effects.

Suggestions that I found on the net were yet all inappropriate (e.g., setting the locale to "danish" will not maintain the native language's spelled weekday names).

Now the only choice I currently see to get the desired behaviour is to change the definition of my native locale in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/de_DE`. This is not a perfect solution since with system updates those changed files may be overwritten again.

My questions are:

1. Are there any better locale related options to get the desired function than changing the specific system locale file?
2. Are there any problems to expect when changing a specific locale definition file? (And how could it be prevented that this file gets overwritten in case of system updates?)
3. Would it be better to define a *new* specific variant of an existing locale file and use that in the `LC_*` settings?  (And how would that new file/definition correctly be made known to the system?)
4. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest you copy the locale file you are interested in, give that copy a unique name (e.g., `en_XX` -- I don't know what the restrictions here are, trial and error might suffice), make whatever changes you want to that, and use it as the locale.  You'll have to regenerate the list or whatever afterward, etc.

Comment: You might want to read my [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203975/best-practice-to-customize-date-time-format-system-wide), which contains details on what I did. I have yet to package it up, but for now this works quite nicely. Simply set `LC_TIME` (in `/etc/environment` or `/etc/default/locale` or `/etc/locale.conf` depending on distro) to the modified locale (I called mine `isodate.UTF-8`) and the respective format will get picked from that customized locale for only time/date. This is how I customized my otherwise `en_US` setting to display ISO date/time.

Comment: @Janis: on Debian and Ubuntu you'll also want to put the name of your locale into `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` (or one of the other files in there) and run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as superuser for the locale definition to be compiled. And yes, **setting `LC_TIME`** to point to a customized locale appears to be the least intrusive method of all I've seen so far. That's why your system has global settings where `LC_TIME` can be set different from the "overall locale".

Comment: @0xC0000022L; Your experience here is very valuable. With the suggestions so far I'll go for a new locale file. I'm yet undecided whether I should use the `copy` on sections approach, or keep other sections redundant (so that I can `diff` against the original file).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a [recent question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/203975/5462) I asked what's the best practice for this kind of change. There was no answer yet. However, I can give you the recipe I am using, which has proven to work fine. All the programs pick the date up correctly.

My description is for Ubuntu, but will likely work on Debian and Mint.

### Preparations

Copy the locale you want to customize from `/usr/share/i18n/locales` to a new file. E.g.

```
cp /usr/share/i18n/locales/de_DE /usr/share/i18n/locales/de_DE@isodate
```

Adjust **all** with the exception of the `LC_TIME` sections to:

```
copy "de_DE"
```

Adjust the `LC_TIME` section to match your desired outcome. You can use the settings from my above linked question as a template. It looks like this is pretty much exactly what you want.

If your locale doesn't make use of "AM/PM" notation, set those to empty:

```
t_fmt_ampm ""
am_pm   "";""
```

### Making it known to the system

Edit the file `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` and add the info about your locale definition there. I.e. add a line like this if your file name above was `isodate`, adjust otherwise:

```
de_DE.UTF-8@isodate UTF-8
```

If `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` doesn't exist, create a file of that name. Don't put your changes into the respective `en` or `de` file in that folder, as they may get overwritten as soon as the `language-pack-*-base` and `language-pack-*` packages on your system receive an update.

Now run `dpkg-reconfigure locales`:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales...
  de_DE.UTF-8@isodate... done
  de_DE.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

In your case this will indicate that the `de_DE.UTF-8@isodate` locale has been generated (assuming you have no syntax issues).

Last but not least add the following to `/etc/default/locale`:

```
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8@isodate"
```

This will ensure that **only** `LC_TIME` overrides the default locale defined using `LANG`.

Log in anew and you should be able to see the new ISO date/time when using `date` or other tools using the respective libc runtime function.

---

The intent *here* is to make the least intrusive change while also not working *against* the system (e.g. against package manager and friends). Of course you can also simply create a copy of your locale, install it in a similar fashion as outlined above and then adjust `LANG`. The point is, as long as you don't want to run the risk of your changes being overwritten by a package update, you **have to** use a customized copy (whatever customization you go for; i.e. `copy` or simply keep the sections as they were in the original). And whether you change `LANG` to point to the *full* customized locale definition - **or** whether you *add* `LC_TIME` to point only to the relevant customized section of the same name of a customized locale definition file - you won't get around adjusting one of the global settings.

Comment: As a best-practice, you would suffix your locale with @something like `en_US.UTF-8@isodate`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Hah! Awesome. However, then you cannot `copy` the `LC_IDENTIFICATION` and how would that affect the naming of the files and how you refer to the locale in `/etc/default/locale` and `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` respectively? Can you tell?

Comment: You'd create a `en_US@isodate` definition file and use `localedef` to produce the correct files; see https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/README for details (and https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=localedata/locales/fr_FR@euro for an example).

Comment: @Janis: no. Thanks for spotting the glitch. Corrected it now.

Comment: @StephenKitt: I believe on Debian and Ubuntu referencing the locale in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` and then running `dpkg-reconfigure locales` would be the canonical way. Although underneath this likely also calls `localedef` in the end. I''ll test this and adjust my instructions above accordingly. I need to make sure that the way `LC_TIME` and the `locales` reference the name it'll still work. But thanks for the input. It helped!

Comment: Yes, in any case, you'd want to change the LC_IDENTIFICATION section (en_US@isodate) since it's a different locale, The end command would be `localedef -i en_US@isodate -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8@isodate`, I'm not sure about the Debian-specific configuration, my comment was mostly on how to name the locale.

Comment: As I understand it, on Debian you'd add your locale definition in `/usr/local/share/i18n/locales`, add the supported locale/charmap pairs in `/usr/local/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`, and run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` (see also `/etc/locale.gen`).

Comment: I'm not sure I've done everything correctly, but this is what I've now done: I've created a modified copy `de_DE.UTF-8@isodate` of the original `de_DE` file, added `de_DE.UTF-8@isodate UTF-8` to file `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`, I did **not** do `dpkg-reconfigure locales` but called `localedef -i de_DE.UTF-8@isodate -f UTF-8 de_DE.UTF-8@isodate`, and changed the `LC_*` settings in my `~/.profile`. I did not change the `LC_IDENTIFICATION`. - Using, e.g., `date` on the command line shows the expected results. Other applications (e.g. Thunderbird) do not show the new settings, though.

Comment: @Janis: Other applications are likely not going to make use of your `~/.profile` although they would most likely inherit the global settings if you set it globally. Also, for those a restart of KDE or whatever you are using may be required. I did a full reboot to make sure (although that's probably overkill, too).

Comment: @0xC0000022L; Not sure how other applications obtain the relevant information; Thunderbird has a setting to get the *system defined* date specification. - What I've done was to logoff and login again to an `xfce` session, but I didn't restart the system. I'll try that.

Comment: @Janis: only if you set it in *your* profile, that is decidedly *not* the system locale. It's your user locale.

Comment: @0xC0000022L; But Thunderbird's date format is aware of the locale settings; I can locally (non system wide) change the locale to en_US or da_DK and the display (including the date format) will change accordingly.