# Making ls do a reasonable sort order, but not print Greek characters as "??"

Tags: ls, unicode, coreutils

Suppose I have the following files in a directory

`_y a  b  c  x  z  β`

The following command lists them in the above order, as God intended:

`perl -e '@files = <*>; print join(" ",sort @files)'`

This is what I want to happen when I do an ls. That is, I would like them all displayed properly, including the one with the Greek beta, and I would also like them in some sensible order, such as this one, in which an earlier character in the filename is always more important than a later one, if they differ.

The default behavior of ls on my ubuntu system is to display this:

`a  b  c  x  _y z  β`

This is because it's trying to be human-friendly and not count the underbar as a character. I don't want that behavior.

I can do `alias ls='LANG=C ls'`, which makes sorting not locale-aware. However, the output is then this:

`_y  a  b  c  x z  ??`

So now the Greek letter isn't displayed properly. I suppose this environment variable makes ls interpret everything as single-byte ascii codes, and then the beta is probably some two-byte combination of unprintable characters.

Is there any way to make ls do what I want?

Comment: You have fine-grained control over locale features. For example, the sort order is defined by LC_COLLATE. Setting LANG to Greek and LC_COLLATE to C may solve this.

Comment: What locale are you using

Comment: @roaima: My locale us the default US stuff. The locale command shows everything set to en_US.UTF-8.

Comment: @berndbausch: Yeah, that's the type of solution I'm looking for, if it exists, but I don't know how to do it. For example, `LC_COLLATE="C" LANG="el_EL.UTF-8" ls`  results in ?? for Greek letters.

Comment: Admittedly, the locale business confuses me to no end. Run the `locale` command to see the current settings. Changing environment variables like LC_CTYPE has no effect on that. Changing LC_ALL does, though. I am sure that some combination of LC_* is your solution; I will leave it up to you to figure this out.

Comment: Related, in that I think you're going to need to redefine `_` as having a sortable position in the alphabet, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204328/100397

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your locale is `en_US.UTF-8` and `LC_ALL=C ls` gives you the order you want then

```
LC_COLLATE=C ls
```

should give you the order you want *and* show `β` as `β`.

Setting `LANG` to any UTF-8 locale should show `β` as `β`. You're using `en_US.UTF-8`, so there's no need to change `LANG`.

One of the comments advised "setting `LANG` to Greek and `LC_COLLATE` to `C`". Your try was `LC_COLLATE="C" LANG="el_EL.UTF-8" ls` and it didn't work because:

- the Greek locale is `el_GR.UTF-8`, not `el_EL.UTF-8`;
- even if I'm wrong and `el_EL.UTF-8` exists, you (your OS) have probably never generated localization files from templates for it.

Probably you haven't generated files for `el_GR.UTF-8` either. To get them you need to edit `/etc/locale.gen` and uncomment `el_GR.UTF-8`, then run `sudo locale-gen`. And then `LC_COLLATE=C LANG=el_GR.UTF-8 ls` will work. But again, you don't have to do this, your `en_US.UTF-8` is enough to show `β` as `β`. All you need is `LC_COLLATE=C` to change the sorting order.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine:

```
$ env LC_COLLATE=C ls
_y  a  b  c  x  z  β
```

I think in your comment you specified bad locale, like this (I needed `-N` to replicate your output):

```
$ env LC_COLLATE=C LANG="sdjf" ls
 _y   a   b   c   x   z  ''$'\316\262'
$ env LC_COLLATE=C LANG="sdjf" ls -N
_y  a  b  c  x  z  ??
```

If you only have broken locale you can use flags `--show-control-chars -N` like this:

```
$ env LC_COLLATE=C LANG="sdjf" ls --show-control-chars -N
_y  a  b  c  x  z  β
$ env LANG=C ls -N --show-control-chars
_y  a  b  c  x  z  β
```

I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 if it matters